# Cocos2d-x : convertToWorldSpace gives wrong position of node

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i have confusion here i have this sprites hierarchy

```
MasterSprite
           | -------- SpriteContainer 
                               | ---------------------SpriteNode1
```

i like to convert the SpriteNode1 position ot world position ( not sure about this ) that is 
that the SpriteNode1 position will be as it was if it was MasterSprite child ( is it world position ? ).
i tried:

```
Vec2 newPos = MasterSprite->convertToNodeSpace(SpriteNode1->getPosition());
Vec2 newPos2 = MasterSprite->convertToWorldSpace(SpriteNode1->getPosition());
Vec2 newPos3 = MasterSprite->convertToNodeSpaceAR(SpriteNode1->getPosition());
Vec2 newPos4 = MasterSprite->convertToWorldSpaceAR(SpriteNode1->getPosition());
```

but none gave me the right position . what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: MasterSprite.position? convertToWorldSpace should work but this will not give you mastersprite position but the mastersprite position plus spritecontainer position plus spritenode1 position. It's not clear what you mean by "right" position.

Comment: The solution is if someone is searching : 
didn't found any explanation of the logic but this is how it done
SpriteContainer->convertToWorldSpace(SpriteNode1->getPosition());

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it right now is that Node-space is local to that node, and World-space is global space (but not necessarily screen-space, because of 3D cameras or whatever).

The so if you want to get a position of one node's position relative to another, you first convert that node's position to world-space, using it's parent, then using the other target parent's convertToNodeSpace.

So if you want the globalized position of a node,

```
Vec2 node_space_pos = my_node->getPosition(); //this is the node's node-space position
Vec2 world_space_pos = my_node->getParent()->convertToWorldSpace(node_space);
```

then in the root scene or whatever is relevant to you, you'd take the world-space/universal coords and convert it to the root node's local-space:

```
Vec2 root_local_pos = root_scene->convertToNodeSpace(world_space_pos);
my_node->removeFromParent();
root_scene->addChild(my_node);
my_node->setPosition(root_local_pos);
```

Now `my_node` is still in the absolute same position on screen, but now it's a child of the root scene instead of wherever else in the graph it was before.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can obtain the WorldSpace position of a node by using

`auto pos = node->getParent()->convertToWorldSpace(node->getPosition());`